# Search literal strings in MS Outlook client with Exchange account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I almost can't believe it but it doesn't work. MS Office Prof. 2016.

Searching for "On the day 21 september" gives 6 mails in the complete mailbox, including items on the server. Only one of them contains the exact literal frase, as expected. Why do the other 5 mails show up?

I believe Outlook treats the search as
On && the && day && 21 && september.
Indeed all words are present in the 5 other mails, but not as the exact string  "On the day 21 september".

Without the quotes of using ""..."" or '...' instead of "..." it appears Outlook treats the search as
On || the || day || 21 || september
so a great lot of mails are returned.

It is quite silly and I know "MS logic" is silly at times, but maybe I am mistaken and somebody knows a better way to search?

Comment: Your question is answered at [How to search for an exact match to character strings/phrase in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3624-outlook-search-exact-match.html#search_exact_match_in_mail_folders)

Comment: What you found is at least something, thank you for that.
Still rather silly to hide it there and you know that among hundreds of field names  you have to select Subject and Message.

Comment: You might get better results if you try something like... +term1 +term2 +term3 , but it will still find messages with all the terms in it.  Perhaps I should say different, rather than better.

Comment: DavidPostill is right.  If you're using Outlook 2016, it's Search Tools > Advanced Find > add your phrase in double quotes , change In: to be subject and message body > Find Now    .  This way you shouldn't get matches on a subset or differently ordered set of words.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known issue.  MS article says to add a value in HKCU, but as a regular user under Win10 1803, the branch is actually locked down.  Run as admin and edit the appropriate hive under HKU.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Search
Type: REG_DWORD
Name: AllowPhraseMatch
Value: 1

ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3054852/unexpected-search-results-when-you-use-double-quotation-marks-to-searc

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office does not exist

Answer (score 0):

According to the official article below, to search for an exact string, you must use quotation marks:

[Learn to narrow your search criteria for better searches in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da)

Comment: As you can see in my question the documentation is wrong or it should work but doesn't. Or perhaps a language, keyboard issue. Try it and see that this part of the documentation is incorrect. The remark of @DavidPostill works.